# Sentence: “I had got one over on the man.”

Tags: idioms

I came across this sentence: “ ***I had got one over on the man.***”

Does it mean that somehow ... he won the first round in a battle?

Can it be a nice way to put it sometimes? Good colloquial English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I came across this sentence: “ I had got one over on the man.”
>
> Does it mean that somehow ... he won the first round in a battle?

No it means that you have had a small victory over the man. You have fooled the man.

[get one over on](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+one+over+on)

Comment: Depending on context, "the man" can mean "legal authorities", especially if ["The Man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man) is capitalized.  So "I had got one over on The Man" could mean that you committed some infraction or crime and you were not caught or punished by the authorities.